# Raspbian command usermod

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, linux, bash

I have a question about usermod this command. I type as below:

`sudo usermod -G adm -a pi`
It is a normal way to append group "adm" to "pi" my raspberry.
If I want to continue to append a lot of group such dialout, chrom, sudo, audio and others, how can I just type one script command only to make all groups to be? Currently, I append them each by each.

Wrong syntax: `sudo user -G adm dialout chrom sudo -a pi`

By the way, are there any books for dummies about this topics? I want to learn about shell-script, bash and more elaborate or essential commands about raspbian. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the syntax for a command by reading the man page (Linux's built in help files):

```
man useradd
```

The relevant section is:

> -G, --groups GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
>              A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member
>              of. Each group is separated from the next by a comma, with no
>              intervening whitespace. The groups are subject to the same
>              restrictions as the group given with the -g option. The default
>              is for the user to belong only to the initial group.

You need to separate the groups with a comma and remove the whitespace, like this:

```
sudo usermod -G adm,dialout,chrom,sudo -a pi
```

As for a book, I started with *[Linux for Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118844351)* way back in the mid 90's. The Raspberry Pi Foundation also publishes several ebooks, including *[Conquer the Command Line](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/essentials-bash-vol1/)* - which is free.

I can also recommend the *[Intro to Linux](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-0)* course from EdX

Comment: I hope that *Conquer the Command Line* is illustrated featuring Coco, the Cantankerous Canary who talks like a parrot: "Use commas and beware of whitespace, squawk!".  Otherwise they need a second addition.

Comment: Thanks all. I fixed and rebuilt the group for my account.